# Detect last iteration of loop in POSIX sh

Tags: shell-script, shell

In POSIX sh, is it possible to detect the last iteration of a `for` loop within the loop?

I am trying to fill in the blank in this example code:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

items='1 2 3'
for item in $items; do
    echo "$item"
    # TODO:
    # How do I check whether or not this is the last iteration?
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
items='1 2 3'
for item in $items; do
```

Stores *one* string in one *scalar* variable `$items`, and then that string is subject to IFS-splitting + globbing on the next line because of that unquoted `$items` expansion.

To store several values, you'd want to use an array variable.

POSIX `sh` doesn't have arrays, but it has the positional parameters, that's even what `for` loops on by default:

```
set 1 2 3
i=1
for item do
  if [ "$i" -eq "$#" ]; then
    echo last
  fi
  printf '%s\n' "Current item: $item"
  i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```

Or:

```
set 1 2 3
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
  if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo last
  fi
  printf '%s\n' "Current item: $1"
  shift
done
```

If you still want to split+glob a space-separated `$items` variable, you could still do:

```
set -- $items # $items split+globbed and the result stored in $1, $2...
```

Or if you didn't want to clobber the script's positional parameters, use a function (which has its own set of positional parameters):

```
loop() {
  i=1
  for item do
    if [ "$i" -eq "$#" ]; then
      echo last
    fi
    printf '%s\n' "Current item: $item"
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
  done
}

loop 1 2 3
items='1 2 3'
loop $items
```

Comment: This seems to overwrite the supplied command line arguments (if any). Is there a way to preserve the original command line arguments?

Comment: @Flux, see the *if you didn't want to clobber the script's positional parameters* in the answer.